# Aggregating values from split strings in groupby index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
index  name     value
1      Foo      9
2      Bar      11
3      Foo      2
4      Bar      4
5      Foo,Bar  3
```

If I do `df.groupby('name').count()` I get:

```
         value
name
Foo      2
Bar      2
Foo,Bar  1
```

I'd like to split `Foo,Bar` and add 1 to each value in the index that exists in the resulting tuple, such that the grouped dataframe looks like:

```
         value
name
Foo      3
Bar      3
```

I can think of ways to do this with `for` loops, but I'm wondering if there's some built-in pandas method for this type of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For pandas 0.25+ use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for `flatten Series`, then for count [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df['name'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts().to_frame('value')
print (df1)
     value
Foo      3
Bar      3
```

For another versions use `split` with `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `flatten Series`:

```
df1 = df['name'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().value_counts().to_frame('value')
print (df1)
     value
Foo      3
Bar      3
```